# axis2, Maven and IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, apache-axis

I am trying to generate Java classes for a Web Service client using axis2. I keep getting a Cannot resolve symbol 'wsname_ServiceStub' The java file is not being picked up. Meanwhile the 'wsname_ServiceCallbackHandler' the java file in the same directory is getting picked up and I can reference to it from the rest of my project.

The file is showing up as a "not a class file" for some reason

I'm using IntelliJ 11.1.2 and Maven 2.2.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>AnotherWS</groupId>
    <artifactId>AnotherWS</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<generateTestcase>true</generateTestcase>-->
                    <!--<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>-->
                    <packageName>wsname</packageName>
                    <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/wsname.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    <!--<generateAllClasses>true</generateAllClasses>-->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```